Css: Before pulse animation is not working
Codepen: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/NWmzmaG
I have a #container that contains four .box elements. Each .box element has a background-image set:

I'm trying to make it so each image changes its opacity by applying pulse animation: However nothing is happening.


#container  {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
}

.box  {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.britannica.com/16/234216-050-C66F8665/beagle-hound-dog.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box::before  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: pulse 2.5s infinite;
}

.box @keyframes pulse  {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>




It's @keyframes not #keyframes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

And @keyframe can't be combined .box. See At-rules.

The absolute ::before element can only fill the entire area of the .box element using inset: 0 if we set the .box element to relative positioning. The absolute child element will then align to the relative position.
The opacity of 0.1 is very subtle and barely noticeable, so I increased it.
The ::before element filled the entire space, but it didn't have a background-color, so I set it to white.
Using @keyframes instead of #keyframes is correct. You don't need to write a class name before it.


#container {
  background-color : orange;
  display          : flex;
  }
.box {
  background-image  : url(https://picsum.photos/100/100);
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-size   : cover;
  width             : 100px;
  height            : 100px;
  margin            : 10px;
  position          : relative; /* added */
  }
.box::before {
  content          : '';
  position         : absolute;
  inset            : 0;
  opacity          : 0;
  background-color : #fff;                /* added */
  animation        : pulse 2.5s infinite;
  }
@keyframes pulse {                        /* changed */
    0% { opacity : 0;   }
   50% { opacity : 0.5; }                 /* changed */
  100% { opacity : 0;   }
  }
<div id='container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>



More information

CSS: position usage - MDN Docs
More information about absolute & relative positions - Stack Overflow answer
Position absolute with relative parent element - Stack Overflow answer
CSS: @keyframes - MDN Docs

